# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "CAE_Model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 576, 704, 3), found shape=(32, 704, 3)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution, encoder, decoder

[image]
[image]
error while model.fit
second screenshot

Tried reshaping, and give on the param out_put shape, BTW it doesn't exist

Help, second day trying to fix that`

Comment: what is your IMG_SHAPE?

Comment: ( 576, 704, 32)

Comment: Please do not include images of code/data/errors. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

BTW, the answer was easy. Due to the fact that Autoencode trying to move from 3 to 4 dimension in ndarray, and while moving having a problems. So we need to add 1 dimension before.

ex:

```py
test_data = [x, y, z]
temp = test_data[np.newaxis, ...] # so we get test_data = [1, x, y, z]
```